# Is there a max price limit for in app purchases?

Tags: ios, price, in-app-purchase

I would like to know if there is a max price limit for an in-app item.
I couldn't get a direct answer from Apple.

Answer (score 5):

The highest tier is **tier 87**. This equates to $999.99 or £699.99.

<sup>Source: App Store Pricing Matrix (requires iTunes Connect; dynamic link)</sup>